# What is the difference between z3c.recipe.scripts and zc.recipe.egg?

Tags: python, buildout

Both z3c.recipe.scripts and zc.recipe.egg seem to be actively developed.

z3c.recipe.scripts is described as:

> The script recipe installs eggs into a buildout eggs directory, exactly like zc.recipe.egg, and then generates scripts in a buildout bin directory with egg paths baked into them.

zc.recipe.egg is described as:

> The egg-installation recipe installs eggs into a buildout eggs directory. It also generates scripts in a buildout bin directory with egg paths baked into them.

So what's the difference? Do I need both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need both. Apparently, `z3c.recipe.scripts` has some improvements over `zc.recipe.egg`:

> - The interpreter generated by the script supports all interpreter options, as opposed to the subset provided by zc.recipe.egg.
> - Both scripts and interpreters from this recipe can optionally choose to include site-packages, and even sitecustomize.

These options are described in more detail on the [`z3c.recipe.scripts` PyPI page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.recipe.scripts).

If you do not understand what these options mean, you probably do not need to use `z3c.recipe.eggs` at all; just stick with `zc.recipe.egg`, which is maintained as part of the `zc.buildout` core.

Comment: Interesting... do you have any idea why these improvements weren't simply done to zc.recipe.egg instead of making a new recipe?

Comment: Not really. I just saw that the z.r.scripts dev is Gary Poster, whom I greatly respect, he must have had his reasons. You could perhaps mail him and ask. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**zc.recipe.egg**

The egg recipe installes one or more eggs, with their dependencies. It installs their console-script entry points with the needed eggs included in their paths. It is suitable for use with a "clean" Python: one without packages installed in site-packages.

**z3c.recipe.scripts**

Like zc.recipe.egg, this recipe builds interpreter scripts and entry point scripts based on eggs. It can be used with a Python that has packages installed in site-packages, such as a system Python. The interpreter also has more features than the one offered by zc.recipe.egg.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout/1.6.3#creating-new-buildouts-and-bootstrapping